# Accessing a Duplicate Rule's Matching rules via Apex

Tags: duplicate-management

I'm trying to access the matching rules associated to a Duplicate rule via code. Through the UI, it's easy enough to create a Duplicate Rule then add Matching rules to it. So I know there has to be a link between these objects, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to make this link through code.

Here is an idea of what I'm trying to do. (which obviously does not work)

> SELECT Id, DuplicateRuleId (<- not correct, but this is what I need)
>   FROM MatchingRule
>   WHERE DuplicateRuleId = (Some specific Duplicate Rule Id)

Does anyone have any ideas on how this would be possible?

Comment: please consider marking my answer as best answer so more people will see and upvote the idea for SF to expose this data in apex. I really don't care about the points or reputation or whatever. I just want this idea implemented already - it makes no sense why this can't be done today. Salesforce needs to fix this once and for all!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the describe information that points to a link between the two accessible in SOQL or Apex. I can't find any documentation that shows where you can retrieve the related matching rule from the duplicate rule or vice versa in SOQL or Apex.

You can do this with the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_duplicaterule.htm) if that's an option. The `duplicateRuleMatchRules` property contains a list of the related matching rules for the retrieved duplicate rule.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's true that the only option (still, nearly 7 years later) is to use the Metadata API. There are many technical hurdles to this approach however, and it may not be feasible in many situations. It not only requires a [verbose apex library](https://github.com/certinia/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls), as well as an asynchronous callout to the MDAPI, but the return result is a base64Binary zip file which requires further libraries to decode the result (as there are no native methods in apex to do so).

We tried to implement this ourselves, but found the technical hurdles were too great and too many to successfully to do.

Anyone interested in having this should upvote this idea! https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000QMilKUAT/need-ability-in-apex-to-identify-relationship-between-duplicatematching-rules